# Django queryset order by string column as defined ordered

Tags: django, django-queryset

My Table

```
Id       Data
-----------------
1        Yellow
2        Green
3        Red
4        Yellow
```

Using django query set (django 1.3.3, python 2.7, db Postgre), I want to order table by Data column as defined ordered [Yellow, Red, Green], <strike>or order by first letter of Data column (which also give the same result)</strike>

Result

```
Id       Data
-----------------
1        Yellow
4        Yellow
3        Red
2        Green
```

Please help how can I make this work

---

Update: How about order as [Green, Yellow, Red]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
YourModel.objects.order_by('-Data')
```

Note `'-Data'` to order it in reverse order.

Reference: [`order_by`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#order-by)

Comment: I see, this is correct in my case. But how's about [Green, Yello, Red]

Comment: @Hardy, I don't think you can get it in such arbitrary order.